# How do I run a Redux Saga one time to dispatch an action on start up of React App?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am looking to dispatch an action on the start-up of my application, currently, I am using a saga to try to do the dispatching. The intent is to fetch the config from an API in the background once the application starts but for now, I am setting my domain with environment variables.

I wanted this action to be dispatched once, and detached from a specific react component.

domainSaga.js

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { DOMAIN_SET_ACTION, setDomain } from './domainAction';

function* fetchDomain() {
  yield put(
    setDomain(
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN_CODE,
      process.env.REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN_SERVER
    )
  );
}

function* domainSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(DOMAIN_SET_ACTION, fetchDomain);
  yield put(DOMAIN_SET_ACTION); // Error cant dispatch from a saga
  // dispatch set action once and only once here
  // fetchDomain(); calling this runs infinitely and crashes the app
}

export default domainSaga;
```

Is it even possible to have this kind of dispatching with redux saga?

Comment: Just dispatch an action on app mount?

Comment: In saga you have to `put` the action object, same as you would with a dispatch - not just the type.